# Sorting a list according to date with missing date inserts

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sorry for the convoluted title, but I find it to be a convoluted propblem

I have two lists, one of dates and one of counts pr. date.
Like this:

[image: Jumbled list]

I would like it to end up like this:

[image: Sorted list with missing date inserts]

where the dates have been moved to their corresponding cell, according to the time between the two dates.
I would prefer it to be doable in Google Sheets, but if thats impossible, Excel would suffice.
Anyone have a clue of how to this?

Comment: One option is to use `SEQUENCE` to create the dates and then `COUNTIFS` to populate the Count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the sequence of all dates as proposed by @BigBen in the comment using `SEQUENCE` like this

```
=SEQUENCE(MAX($A$1:$A$3)-MIN($A$1:$A$3)+1;1;MIN($A$1:$A$3))
```

And then in the next cell you can insert the following formule

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$1:$C;{$A$1:$B$3};2;FALSE)))
```

[image]

Comment: You could also combine the two in just a single formula, skipping the helper column all-together: `={SEQUENCE(MAX(N31:N)-MIN(N31:N)+1,1,MIN(N31:N)), 
  ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(MAX(N31:N)-MIN(N31:N)+1,1,MIN(N31:N)),{N31:O},2,0)))}`